# Business management tools in political processes

Tags: political-system

I am wondering if there are any countries where any sort of systematic process, change or risk management is used in governing or law-passing.

One example:

- A problem is identified, risk management is used to define a solution.
- A law is passed to mitigate this problem
- After a certain period of time, the problem is reviewed  and the effectiveness of the law is judged. If necessary, the law is adapted or scrapped.

Does any country have political bodies that perform **systematic** management and review of its actions based on business principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Congressional Budget Office](https://www.cbo.gov/) does the "pricing" of various financial outcomes under different "scenarios".